# How to use a merge module in another merge module

Tags: merge, wix

I am creating a Wix installer project (MyProduct.msi) which should consume a WiX merge module (MergeDesktop.msm) which intern consumes another WiX merge module (MergeCore.msm).

I am able to generate MyProduct.msi which can consume MergeCore.msm and it is able to copy content from MergeCore.msm definition.

Though I am able to generate MyProduct.msi which consumes MergeDesktop.msm which intern consumes MergeCore.msm file, it is copying nothing.

I have used Dependency element in MergeDesktop.msm to include MergeCore.msm module.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Module Id="MergeDesktop" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0">
        <Package Id="22c37444-cc56-453c-8906-73413240ae40" Manufacturer="Microsoft" InstallerVersion="200" />
    <Dependency RequiredId="MergeCore" RequiredLanguage="1033"/>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="MergeRedirectFolder">
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Module>
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MergeCore" />
        <Merge Id="MergeCore" Language="1033" SourceFile="MergeCore.msm" DiskId="1" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Could you please suggest what is the best way to deal with this situation. Please let me know if further information is needed.

Regards,
Kumar

Comment: A couple of points: first, an MSM can not 'consume' another MSM as a dependency. What the <Dependency> element does is tell the MSI that if module 'A' depends on module 'B', then if you consume 'A' you also have to consume 'B'. Second, I don't see the SourceFile attribute getting set for the "MergeDesktop" <Module> element...

Comment: Hi jbudreau, Thank you for your response. My response as below.

1. I understood that **dependency** tag is not the appropriate tag for referring a msm module in another msm project. Can I ask you what would be the appropriate solution for this?

2. Do mean that SourceFile attribute of "MergeDesktop" <Module> element should be set with location of **MergeCore.msm** ?? but, I could not see SourceFile attribute for <Module> element but able to find the SourceFile attribute for <Merge> element. Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the "MergeDesktop" MSM requires that that "MergeCore" MSM also be packaged into the same MSI, then I would remove the <Merge Id="MergeCore"...> element from the "MergeDesktop" source file above and just leave the <Dependency RequiredId="MergeCore"...> element. Then, have your MyProduct.msi explicitly package both the "MergeDesktop" and "MergeCore" MSMs. In short, have the MSI consume the two MSMs, not an MSI that consumes an MSM that consumes another MSM (I don't think this is even possible in WiX)...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use a merge module inside of another merge module.

The right way to do it is when you build your msi, merge both modules.
If you have dependencies of one module from the other you specify this with < Dependency >

https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization/mergers/